# Node APP running under PM2 unable to run child process

Tags: node.js, child-process, pm2

I have a NodeJS app that is running under PM2 to keep the process running.  The node app has a function to run a child process to execute a command to run some image processing.  Everything worked great in localhost using nodemon.  But on my DO server, with PM2, the child process just doesn't run, no error or anything.  Any ideas?? Thanks!

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var primExec = exec(
  `primitive -i ${__dirname}/client/users/${username}/${fileName} -o ${__dirname}/client/users/${username}/P-${fileName} -n 50 -v`
);
```

I can run the app on DO with `node` command and it works as intended.  It's only when pm2 is managing the process.

Comment: Well, I just ran it locally with PM2, and worked as expected, but can't repeat this on my DO server

Comment: The process started working as expected after I reset the server, not sure why it needed that.