# child process not spawned/working under PM2 for Node

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

It's almost exactly as this:
[Node APP running under PM2 unable to run child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56524912/node-app-running-under-pm2-unable-to-run-child-process)

but no answers (and the OP's restart didn't work for me)

I have the following issue:

NodeJS / Express app
Works fine when run as `npm run dev` without turning it into a background process

The app internally spawns a child process, like this:

```
 let exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec)
 const ret = await exec(ps, encoding: "utf-8"})
```

**Note**: I tried the sync version with `execSync` and the same issue persists, so it doesn't seem to be related to async/await.

**Note 2** PM2 on my local macOS, exact same version `5.1.0` seems to work fine. So this is something about the Digital Ocean VPS server I think. What could it be?

This works just fine on my local machine and also on the Digital Ocean VPS so long as it's not run as a pm2 process

`sudo pm2 start myapp`

No error messages, nothing - the app serves just fine and does everything else, *except* the part where I need to do an `exec` to run a command. Super frustrating!

Anyone have any ideas?

thank you

Comment: I assume your VPS is a linux machine right?

Comment: @slebetman I resolved this and added an answer

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this. Answering my own question for the benefit of others.

The issue was that I was creating a path within the code using `process.env.PWD` - this worked in my local host and ALSO when not run as PM2.

Turns out that when we use PM2 to fork off the process, it doesn't pick the PWD (e.g. `/root/myapp`) which becomes `undefined` causing the `fs` actions and `exec` to fail.

I added `PWD=/root/myapp` in the `.env` and monitored it with `pm2 logs` and everything worked.